# MySQL: How to show all courses available and in another column in which ones a specific user is already enrolled in?

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I want to show all the courses in the MySQL database, and show in which ones a specific use is enrolled in.

My database structure is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE usuarios(
    userID int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
    userName char(50) null,
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE cursos (
    cursoID int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
    nombreCurso char(100) not null,
    estadoCurso char(50) not null,
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE cursosUsuarios (
    cursosUsuariosID int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
    userID int not null,
    cursoID int not null,
    userHabilitado int(1) not null DEFAULT '0',
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

If I do have this information:

> UserID Alfa is enrolled in cursoID A and B
>
> UserID Beta is enrolled in cursoID A and C
>
> UserID Gamma is enrolled in cursoID C
>
> UserID Delta is enrolled in cursoID D
>
> UserID Epsylon is enrolled in cursoID C and E

**How can I show a list of all courses but showing in that list what courses does belong user Alfa?**
Like this:

> Curso ID ========== User ID
>
> A        ========== Alfa
>
> B        ========== Alfa
>
> C        ========== NULL
>
> D        ========== NULL
>
> E        ========== NULL

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the output lists all the courses where a particular user might not take the course so that you need to make a `left join` among `cursos` table and `cursosUsuarios`, `usuarios` tables while making the `cursos` table as the left table.

```
SELECT 
C.nombreCurso,
U.userName
FROM cursos C 
LEFT JOIN cursosUsuarios CU ON CU.cursoID = C.cursoID
LEFT JOIN usuarios U ON U.userID = CU.userID AND U.userID = <PUT THE USERID OF Alfa here>;
```